# CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: - [Clojure]

Tags: clojure

I have this `save-message` function in `guestbook.models.db` namespace and I am trying to run it in the repl but I get this:

```
guestbook.models.db> (save-message "A" "Hi"
                                   )
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: save-message in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/xc/ypy3lqhj08xg2hjc6g81qwl80000gn/T/form-init7598384514150426113.clj:1:1)
```

I reload and try again and I get the same error

```
guestbook.models.db> (:reload 'guestbook.models.db)
nil
guestbook.models.db> (save-message "A" "Hi"
                                   )
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: save-message in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/xc/ypy3lqhj08xg2hjc6g81qwl80000gn/T/form-init7598384514150426113.clj:1:1) 
guestbook.models.db>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to say

```
(require :reload 'guestbook.models.db)
```

This reloads this single namespace; if you use `:reload-all` instead, it will also recursively reload all namespaces loaded by `guestbook.models.db`, directly or indirectly.

See `(doc require)` for details.

---

As for `(:reload 'guestbook.models.db)`:

Keywords in Clojure, when used as functions, attempt to treat their first argument as a map to look themselves up in. For example, `(:foo {:foo 1})` returns `1`. If this argument cannot be so treated, `nil` is returned. Optionally a second argument can be provided, to be returned as the default value in case the keyword fails to find a value corresponding to itself in its first argument (whether it happens to be a non-map or a map which has no entry for this key).

Comment: I get the same error when I try `(require :reload 'guestbook.models.db)`: `guestbook.models.db> (require :reload 'guestbook.models.db)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: require in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/xc/ypy3lqhj08xg2hjc6g81qwl80000gn/T/form-init7598384514150426113.clj:1:1)`

Comment: This one is about `require`. How did you switch to `guestbook.models.db` in the REPL? `in-ns` or something editor-specific by any chance? You need to `(require 'guestbook.models.db)` at the REPL *before* switching to it with `in-ns` (or use a function of your editor that loads the namespace properly before switching to it), otherwise you'll switch to a newly created namespace of this name without the basic scaffolding such as `clojure.core` being pulled in, which clearly happened here.

Comment: Oh, you should be able to fix this by saying `(clojure.core/require :reload 'guestbook.models.db)`.

Comment: You must have used `in-ns` (or some editor feature that relies on it directly) to switch to `guestbook.models.db` without loading it from the source file. `in-ns` creates completely bare namespaces which don't even refer to symbols from `clojure.core` (see `(doc refer)`) and is not interested in source files at all. Instead you should first load your source file (for example using `require`). Once the namespace is loaded, `in-ns` can be used to switch to it.

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior when loading the namespace like this: (ns guestbook.repl): (start-server)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: start-server in this context, compiling:(C:\Users\Simeon\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init6442755879023838607.clj:1:1) .   Does it also behaves similar to in-ns and needs a requre command?  Would (use guestbook.repl) have the same effect?  Thanks.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon `(ns foo)` won't load `foo` from disk – it'll create a new namespace called `foo` if one doesn't already exist. So yes, you'll have to `require` or `use` your namespace.